# Scripts to parse and download iTunes Connect and AppStore data

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm looking for recommendations of a script or series of scripts that download and parse iTunes Connect sales data and AppStore comments, ratings and rankings data for a defined app.

I'm also aware of solutions like:

- <del>[AppViz](http://www.ideaswarm.com/products/appviz/)</del>
- <del>[appsales-mobile](http://code.google.com/p/appsales-mobile/)</del> (dead)
- <del>[iphone-stats](http://github.com/kasatani/iphone-stats/tree/master) (dead)</del>
- [Heartbeat.app](http://heartbeatapp.com) (dead)

I'm sure I'll find a few more with more searching.

I can't help but feel there must be a really decent set of open source scripts out there to do this, given how many developers are now writing apps for the AppStore.

Would be interested to hear any commercial offerings as well (although my personal preference is for open source, so I can at least see what it is doing with my iTunes Connect login credentials).

To be clear, I'm really looking for something that hits all of the areas mentioned:

**App Store** (per store)

- Comments
- Ratings
- Category/store rankings

**iTunes Connect**

- The contents of the sales reports

Analysis/graphs of the data is not necessary (but would be a nice to have I guess). I'm not really looking for something like AppSales Mobile above, I would like the raw data so I can do my own analysis and formatting. So far it looks like AppViz (listed above) is the best out there.

Any suggestions on what is good/available or should I just go roll my own?

Comment: I want to draw attention to the fact that Apple has their own official tool now, see [pojo's answer for the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7593991/10947).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'm not doing dev for iOS at the moment so it is slightly more difficult for me to judge the answer. Given it is the official mechanism I'll change the accepted answer to pojo's, unless there is violent disagreement.

Comment: Related: We wrote this for my company to handle just financial info so we could pay licensees their portion of sales. It does currency conversion and splits out earnings by app for Apple, Google and Amazon stores: https://github.com/eggheadgames/app_earnings. Feel free to use & improve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Could the official AutoIngest tool from Apple be of use? [See section 3.2](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf)</strike>

Edit: As of December 6, 2016, Autoingest is deprecated by the [Reporter](https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itcbe21ac7db) tool. You should use that instead.

Comment: Looks like you need to run this on osX, so a nonstarter for me since i'm on windows

Comment: Autoingest is a Java class, so it runs fine on Windows assuming you have Java installed.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz Actually it can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24442584/1171701 
Also see the Apple docs: 
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/Books_Payments_Finance_Reports_Guide.pdf

Comment: @RichardBuckingham Of course, so I deleted my comment. Maybe it wasn't possible (or just not documented) back then, not sure.

Comment: "Reporter is a command-line tool that you can use to download your Sales and Trends reports and Payments and Financial Reports." - so it's totally not about ratings and comments.

Answer (score 21):

[www.appannie.com](http://www.appannie.com) is a relatively new site that does all the things you mentioned. I think it's in line with what you are looking for because it's focused on being simple and easy to use.

It's free right now so you might want to give it a shot.

Comment: Looks pretty promising service. Well executed.

Answer (score 8):

Check out www.appfigures.com, it covers pretty much all of the above and includes: automatic report downloading (and archiving with full access), various interactive sales reports by date, country, region, etc., reviews from all app stores (123), and rank trending in top 400 for all countries.

It also sends reports by email so you dont even have to login.

And its free (while in beta)

Comment: It's actually top 200 from all app stores now, and updated hourly :)

Comment: +1, as long as it stays free. :) If it goes paid, I'm rolling my own. The technical information is all out there.

Comment: The free account is "free forever", and there's no data sharing or aggregation.

Comment: Looks like a great site you have there! I'll give it a shot for sure.

Comment: Update: Costs money now

Answer (score 4):

For ranking details, check out this article

[Scraping AppStore Reviews](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/08/scraping-appstore-reviews.html)

Many of the comments also go on to develop the work done on the page.

For comments there's an Adobe Air application that collects store comments worldwide
[available from here](http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/12/25/iphone-app-reviews-air-application/) but I don't believe the source is available. However, it proves it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

This only covers reviews, but it work for that, and free: [AppsReviewFinder](http://www.massycat.co.uk/iphonedev/AppReviewsFinder/)

Comment: AppReviewFinder yay! Multiple selection in the product list (or "Get all apps' reviews" command) would be most welcome, though.

Answer (score 2):

The Rogue Amoeba guys cooked up [iTunesConnectArchiver](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/utm/2009/05/04/itunesconnectarchiver/) for persisting and storing the raw data. I haven't used it so I'm not sure if handle comments/ratings or just sales data, but the code is available and it seems like a good starting point at least

Answer (score 2):

I've written a C# application to get and display all the comments from all the AppStores.

**Update:** It's not a script, but the source code is available at GitHub (http://github.com/berzniz/SimpleAppReviews/) so you can extend it.

Currently it can:

- Download all comments and ratings per store
- Display the reviews in a sortable table
- Export data to CSV

You can get it here: [SimpleAppReviews](http://www.ketacode.com/simpleappreviews/)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow me to promote my own little script here: I have written a Ruby script to format the raw Financial Reports from iTunes Connect to a nice HTML table. It doesn't download the files from iTunesConnect so you'd have to use one of the other tools before. You can [get the script on GitHub](http://github.com/ole/itunesconnect-financialreports).

Answer (score 0):

I use [WWW::iTunesConnect](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::iTunesConnect) but that's because I wrote it

Comment: That's not too surprising. I haven't looked at that code in ages. Feel free to send a pull request if you know how to fix it. I don't really have the time, or need, to look into it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in a script I wrote to check for apps being featured on the App Store homepage, in What's new, What's hot or Staff picks:

http://www.futuretap.com/blog/scraping-app-store-featured-entries/

Answer (score 0):

I have started a project for this over at Sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/itunesanalytics/. It's in a planning stage now, but if anyone wants to join in, I think that there's potential for a simple, powerful, open-source, free, self-hosted web app. I'm thinking something that pulls down the data, adding it to a database, and then gives the graphs and views that many of the other projects here are trying to create.

There are more than a few features that I think are desirable, but getting some code up and running and out there would probably go a long way to getting more people involved.

It might be a good time for me to learn Ruby on Rails.

Comment: or maybe you try yii for this projoject?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small script to sync the last 12 months of financial reports (not the sales but the payment reports) from iTunes Connect:

https://gist.github.com/futuretap/69c6289e791b10b43fba

It's based on Apples Autoingestion tool.