# Automatically download sales reports from iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect, web-scraping

I had a nice and hacky Perl script to automatically scrape and download sales report files from iTunes Connect.  As of today, Apple overhauled the sales report site.  It looks a lot nicer, but it uses a lot of JavaScript and simple scraping isn't going to work any more.

So, does anybody know of a way to scrape this new site effectively?

Some [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937899/scripts-to-parse-and-download-itunes-connect-and-appstore-data) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619172/itunes-connect-api) point to various scripts and online services.  I presume they are all broken now as well.  If you know of one that is still functional, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/appdailysales/ was just updated to support the Sept 2010 iTunes connect changes.

**Edit**: please use http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/Autoingestion.class.zip or something based on that, like https://github.com/danieldickison/appdailysales

Comment: To be clear, this is not my work. It is http://stackoverflow.com/users/245020/kirby-t

Comment: Is it possible that Apple has changed things again in the last 24 hours?!  I just tried the script v2.0.1 and it's not working (error on line 245: list index out of range)

Comment: Figured it out - there's an error on line 244 (change "value1" to "value")

Comment: Apple recently released a Java command line tool to fetch reports without needing to do any screen scraping.  I've forked appdailysales to call out to this tool, and it works nicely: https://github.com/danieldickison/appdailysales

Comment: Does sales report also tell us no of downloads ?

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.com/viva/status/24133713255

just need to sift through the ajax cruft. if it's even possible. very annoyed with apple at the moment.