# Count iOS App downloads

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

**Problem:** 
 
I'm an app developer and my boss asked me how many times one of our iPhone apps was downloaded

 
**What I tried so far:**
 
Apple statistics:
There seem to be only daily or weekly data. Furthermore, there seem to be no way to access download statistics from previous years.


Services like [www.appannie.com](http://www.appannie.com):
This might work, but I don't really want to give them the email and password of our developer account.


Scraping the data automatically (See: [automatically-download-sales-reports-from-itunes-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682150/automatically-download-sales-reports-from-itunes-connect)):
I don't really want to spend time to set up and maintain such a system unless there is really no other solution.

**My Question:**
Is there a better way? How do other developer find out how many times their app was downloaded?

Comment: The developer Team Agent (only) can access the Sales and Trends module which show Sales Reports for the apps. If you don't see the link to it, you can open the Itunes Connect FAQ (link at bottom of page) and search for "Sales" to find the link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Services like www.appannie.com: This might work, but I don't really
>   want to give them the email and password of our developer account.

i use appAnnie, but i didn't gave them my "email and password of my developer account".

in ItunnesConnect apple site you can create a new account with JUST the privilege to see the reports of a single app, and nothing more

P.S.
This may be very useful in case you want to give access to a client or a developer partner to a single app statistics, as you can create a new appAnnie user with access to just an app.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks very much for this tip. I will try it and if it works, you get the green tick.

Comment: you're welcome. I found that a new ItunnesConnect account with limited privileges may be useful also in case i want to share financial reports with customers or other external partners...

Comment: Can you give more details on how to limit privileges to a single app?
I tried all iTunesconnect options but could not find it.

Comment: in https://itunesconnect.apple.com/  logIn-> then in homePage find link "Manage Users" -> you get a page where you can add a new user: give the new user just the privilege to read sales-app

Comment: The appFigures sharing feature (http://blog.appfigures.com/sharing-apps-is-now-super-easy/) lets you share your sales data for particular products in a flexible and secure way.

Comment: @meronix when [you add a new user](http://s27.postimg.org/kmis9jpib/Screen_Shot_2014_02_28_at_10_28_01_AM.png) on **itunesconnect**.. do you choose *itunes connect user* or just *test user*?

Answer (score 11):

Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well I use [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) to track installs and session. But you will have to add the flurry to your project.

And We als use [AppFigures](https://www.appfigures.com/) to track real downloads, but as you stated you can only retrieve so far back as Apple allows it.
AppFigures will also require you to give them your ItunnesConnect account details.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Flurry. Although it doesn't directly solve the problem at hand, it seems like the best general solution to solve this problem.

Comment: We (appFigures) actually just opened a private beta for new functionality that provides an accurate all-time total for iOS/mac apps regardless of when you sign up. Contact us if you want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes connect app has other selection methods, try it.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect-mobile/id376771144?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

> Services like www.appannie.com:
>   This might work, but **I don't really want to give them the email and password** of our developer account.

That, seems like a very good idea!

Why not hire a sales guy to count the numbers for you? But in all seriousness, I'd go with the scraping option. I believe that's the only viable solution for your problem until Apple comes up with an API.

Comment: We already have people to do mundane jobs. But we call them "Intern", not "Sales guy" ;) However, the problem is the lack of past data.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AppFigures.com](http://appfigures.com), As @meronix suggested create a new user with privileges you specify. AppFigures gives you daily reports emailed to you every morning, in addition to Nicely done graphs and an entire dashboard of information. I recommend!

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information there is another services called [mopapp](http://www.mopapp.com/), it supports several platform.