# get count of my app download in my website

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I want to track the number of installing my app in iOS devices and show that in my website .
I am using Google analytics in my app . can this help me get that info?
or how can I get it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: This may help...

[Count iOS App downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893911/count-ios-app-downloads)

Comment: @Farhan I don't want to change google analytics

Comment: Google gives you a `Core Reporting Api` to extract data from Google Analytics. Do you see reports for the app downloads/new users in your Reporting Console ?

Comment: @SudhirMishra I can't see reports of app downloads in console . if it's exist I can read them by API.. where can I get that in console?

Comment: The reports do have the `# of new users' wouldn't that be same as the number of downloads ? provided you query from the launch date of your app.

Comment: @SudhirMishra excuse me , how can I find that of # new users .. is it in console or API? and is it provide me with particular number of downloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Users Reports** under the Tab `Mobile App Acquistion` in Google Analytics

> This report gives you an overview of the first launches, or the number of visits in which the app is opened for the first time on a device, including the total number of New Users, their Operating System, App Version, and the Country/Territory.

Quoting from the [Google Support docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2568794?hl=en)

You can export the data from Google Analytics and deliver it your web page via `Core Reporting API`

Comment: Seems this is what I was looking for , thank you so much . but I'm wondering , I just have 12 devices installed the app ( still in Ad hoc) but the number in google analytics for new users is 32 .. how??

Comment: and also it's the same number of active users

Comment: As your app is in alpha, you might have `installed-uninstalled-installed` the application on same device a numerous times. This is the possible case you have `12 devices` and `32 new users` in Google Analytics.