# iTunesConnect - Download automatically app's usage analytics

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

[ItunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)'s app analytics page has two sections: Sales and Usage. For the first part, they have [Autoingestion Tool](https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf). I found nothing for **Usage**, and I searched a lot.

The closest one was this question:
[heavy iTunes Connect scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843889/heavy-itunes-connect-scraping), by [philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366967/philipp), almost a year ago.
And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097540/itunesconnect-api-number-of-downloads-of-the-app), also, about a year ago.

Does anyone know if there is a tool like the Autoingestion for Usage (Installations, Sessions, Active Devices, Crashes, etc.)?

[image]