# iTunesConnect Autoingest for financial earnings reports

Tags: report, web-scraping, app-store-connect, financial

Apple has for some time had a tool, AutoIngest.class for downloading iTunes Connect sales and trend reports.

Is there is a similar tool (or modified use of it) to pull the financial reports (more specifically the Earnings report from the "Payments and Financial Reports" page) without manually downloading them for every month/region?

Answer (score 7):

*Edit Jan 2017*: The Autoingestion tool has been retired and replaced with a new one, per https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itc0f2481229

After downloading the `Reporter.zip` with new `.jar` and `.properties` files, and adding your login to the properties file, you can then download the same file as previously using this equivalent command:

```
java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Finance.getReport 80000000, CA, Financial, 2014, 05
```

Some caveats:

- the properties file must be in current directory
- note the leading `00` is no longer needed on the `vendor_id`
- the output is now `Successfully downloaded 80000000_0214_CA.txt.gz` instead of just `80000000_0214_CA.txt.gz` (in case you're scripting this)

I left the older info below to help people transition.

*(end edit)*

**Yes, the same autoingest tool provided by Apple will also download financial reports.** You can find the guide [here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/Apps_Payments_Finance_Reports_Guide.pdf), which states that the command is run with:

```
java Autoingestion <properties_filename> <vendor_id> <region_code>
<report_type> <fiscal_year> <fiscal_period>
```

Notice that the syntax is different from using it for sales reports. E.g. when providing the vendor ID, include two leading zeroes before your vendor ID number.

Thus, I can run it with this command to nominally retrieve the financial report for Canada for 2014 for May (*my vendor number obscured*):

```
java Autoingestion login.properties 0080000000 CA DRR 2014 05
```

Note that the `fiscal_period` is 3 months ahead ([more info](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130247/where-can-i-see-itunes-connect-fiscal-calendar-without-access-to-itunes-connect)), so providing `2014 05` will download the financial report for 02 (February). The resulting file will reflect the actual month sold. I.e. this is the output of the command:

```
80000000_0214_CA.txt.gz
File Downloaded Successfully
```

Thus, as of right now, near the end of June (06), I can run this command:

```
java Autoingestion login.properties 0080000000 AU DRR 2014 08
```

and download the May sales:

```
80000000_0514_AU.txt.gz
File Downloaded Successfully
```

This works as you'd expect across year boundaries. I.e. providing `2015 03` will give me the financial report for Dec 2014. *(Thanks to the comment by @smacdonald for this info)*.

I hope this saves someone else some confusion!  I was looking in StackOverflow for the answer and this question seemed most relevant...

*Slightly related, I have open sourced a tool at https://github.com/eggheadgames/app_earnings that adds the currency data copy-pasted from the relevant ITunesConnect page and then processes these files into per-app earnings in a single currency, regardless of country of sale. Right now the tool handles Google Play, Amazon and Apple reports.*

Comment: As of 5 Nov 2014, this doesn't appear to be working anymore -- perhaps related to the iTunes store changes made recently. (It worked 30 days ago...).  I'll update this if I find a workaround.

Comment: As of 9 Feb 2015, this is working again, still with the 3 month offset. I.e. fetching 2015 03 resulted in data for 2014 12.

Comment: I assume the three month offset is because Apple's fiscal periods (the <fiscal_period> argument) aren't the same as calendar months. Fiscal period 01 = Oct. See Apple's fiscal calendar for more details: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130247/where-can-i-see-itunes-connect-fiscal-calendar-without-access-to-itunes-connect

Answer (score 1):

App Sales is an excellent tool for this. You can get it from GitHub:
https://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on mm2001's great answer, I've written a small script to sync the last 12 months of financial reports from iTunes Connect:

https://gist.github.com/futuretap/69c6289e791b10b43fba